# How to change success order status in payumoney in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, payment-methods

I am using Payumoney payment method in Magento after successful order the status becomes processing. I have made a new status paid which status code is paid and assigned in new state which is not default. I want to set this status for success order here is my code please help to do it. thanks in advance...

```
     <?php

     class Payu_PayuCheckout_Model_Shared extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {

         protected $_code = 'payucheckout_shared';
         protected $_isGateway = false;
         protected $_canAuthorize = false;
         protected $_canCapture = true;
         protected $_canCapturePartial = false;
         protected $_canRefund = false;
         protected $_canVoid = false;
         protected $_canUseInternal = false;
         protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
         protected $_canUseForMultishipping = false;
         protected $_formBlockType = 'payucheckout/shared_form';
         protected $_paymentMethod = 'shared';
         protected $_order;

         public function cleanString($string) {

             $string_step1 = strip_tags($string);
             $string_step2 = nl2br($string_step1);
             $string_step3 = str_replace("<br />", "<br>", $string_step2);
             $cleaned_string = str_replace("\"", " inch", $string_step3);
             return $cleaned_string;
         }

         /**
          * Get checkout session namespace
          *
          * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Session
          */
         public function getCheckout() {
             return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
         }

         /**
          * Get current quote
          *
          * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
          */
         public function getQuote() {
             return $this->getCheckout()->getQuote();
         }

         /**
          * Get order model
          *
          * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
          */
         public function getOrder() {
             if (!$this->_order) {
                 $paymentInfo = $this->getInfoInstance();
                 $this->_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                         ->loadByIncrementId($paymentInfo->getOrder()->getRealOrderId());
             }
             return $this->_order;
         }

         public function getCustomerId() {
             return Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/' . $this->getCode() . '/customer_id');
         }

         public function getAccepteCurrency() {
             return Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/' . $this->getCode() . '/currency');
         }

         public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
             return Mage::getUrl('payucheckout/shared/redirect');
         }

         /**
          * prepare params array to send it to gateway page via POST
          *
          * @return array
          */
         public function getFormFields() {

             $billing = $this->getOrder()->getBillingAddress();
             $shipping = $this->getOrder()->getShippingAddress();
             $addr_entity_id = $shipping->getCustomerAddressId();
             $shippingaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');
             $shippingaddress->load($addr_entity_id);
             $shipaddgetdat = $shippingaddress->getData();



             $biladdr_entity_id = $billing->getCustomerAddressId();
             ;
             $billingaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');
             $billingaddress->load($biladdr_entity_id);
             $billaddgetdat = $billingaddress->getData();

             $coFields = array();
             $items = $this->getQuote()->getAllItems();

             if ($items) {
                 $i = 1;
                 foreach ($items as $item) {
                     if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                         continue;
                     }
                     $coFields['c_prod_' . $i] = $this->cleanString($item->getSku());
                     $coFields['c_name_' . $i] = $this->cleanString($item->getName());
                     $coFields['c_description_' . $i] = $this->cleanString($item->getDescription());
                     $coFields['c_price_' . $i] = number_format($item->getPrice(), 2, '.', '');
                     $i++;
                 }
             }

             $request = '';
             foreach ($coFields as $k => $v) {
                 $request .= '<' . $k . '>' . $v . '</' . $k . '>';
             }


             $key = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/key');
             $salt = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/salt');
             $debug_mode = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/debug_mode');

             $orderid = $this->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
             $orderInfo = $this->getOrder();
             $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
     // get order total value
             $orderValue = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.', $thousands_sep = '');
     // get order item collection
             $orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
             $productInfo = array();
             $productInfo2 = array();


             foreach ($orderItems as $item) {

                 $item->getName();
                 $product_id = $item->product_id;
                 $product_sku = $item->sku;
                 $product_name = $item->getName();
                 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
                 $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
                 $category_id = $cats[0]; // just grab the first id
                 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
                 $category_name = $category->getName();

                // $productInfo['name'] = $this->cleanString($item->getName());
                 //$productInfo['description'] = $this->cleanString(substr($_product->getDescription(),0,50));
                 //$productInfo['value'] = $orderValue;
                 //$productInfo['isRequired'] = true;
                 //$productInfo['settlementEvent'] = "EmailConfirmation";
                 //$productInfo2[] = $productInfo;
             }
            // $productIndoFilterData['paymentParts'] = $productInfo2;
             //$jsonProductInfo = json_encode($productIndoFilterData);

             $txnid = $orderid;
             $productinfo = 'Product Information';
             $coFields['key'] = $key;
             $coFields['txnid'] = $txnid;
             $coFields['udf2'] = $txnid;
             $coFields['amount'] = number_format($this->getOrder()->getBaseGrandTotal(), 0, '', '');
             $coFields['productinfo'] = $productinfo;
             $coFields['address'] = $billaddgetdat['street'];
             $coFields['firstname'] = $billing->getFirstname();
             $coFields['Lastname'] = $billing->getLastname();
             $coFields['City'] = $billing->getCity();
             $coFields['State'] = $billing->getRegion();
             $coFields['Country'] = $billing->getCountry();
             $coFields['Zipcode'] = $billing->getPostcode();
             $coFields['email'] = $this->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail();
             $coFields['phone'] = $billing->getTelephone();

             $coFields['ship_name'] = $shipping->getFirstname() . " " . $shipping->getLastname();
             $coFields['ship_address'] = $shipaddgetdat['street'];
             $coFields['ship_zipcode'] = $shipping->getPostcode();
             $coFields['ship_city'] = $shipping->getCity();
             $coFields['ship_state'] = $shipping->getRegion();
             $coFields['ship_country'] = $shipping->getCountry();
             $coFields['ship_phone'] = $shipping->getTelephone();
             $coFields['website'] = Mage::getBaseUrl();
             $coFields['surl'] = Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'payucheckout/shared/success/';
             $coFields['furl'] = Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'payucheckout/shared/failure/';
             $coFields['curl'] = Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'payucheckout/shared/canceled/id/' .
 $this->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
             $coFields['Pg'] = $billing->getpg();
             $coFields['bankcode'] = $billing->getbankcode();
             $coFields['ccnum'] = $billing->getccnum();
             $coFields['ccvv'] = $billing->getccvv();
             $coFields['ccexpmon'] = $billing->getccexpmon();
             $coFields['ccexpyr'] = $billing->getccexpyr();
             $coFields['ccname'] = $billing->getccname();
             $coFields['service_provider'] = 'payu_paisa';

             $debugId = '';


             if ($debug_mode == 1) {

                 $requestInfo = $key . '|' . $coFields['txnid'] . '|' . $coFields['amount'] . '|' .
                         $productinfo . '|' . $coFields['firstname'] . '|' . $coFields['email'] . '|' . $debugId . '||||||||||' . $salt;
                 $debug = Mage::getModel('payucheckout/api_debug')
                         ->setRequestBody($requestInfo)
                         ->save();

                 $debugId = $debug->getId();

                 $coFields['udf1'] = $debugId;
                 $coFields['Hash'] = hash('sha512', $key . '|' . $coFields['txnid'] . '|' . $coFields['amount'] . '|' .
                         $productinfo . '|' . $coFields['firstname'] . '|' . $coFields['email'] . '|' . $debugId . '|' . $coFields['udf2'] .
 '|||||||||' . $salt);
             } else {
                 $coFields['Hash'] = strtolower(hash('sha512', $key . '|' . $coFields['txnid'] . '|' . $coFields['amount'] . '|' .
                                 $productinfo . '|' . $coFields['firstname'] . '|' . $coFields['email'] . '||' .
 $coFields['udf2'] . '|||||||||' . $salt));
             }
             return $coFields;
         }

         /**
          * Get url of Payu payment
          *
          * @return string
          */
         public function getPayuCheckoutSharedUrl() {
             $mode = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/demo_mode');

             $url = 'https://test.payu.in/_payment.php';

             if ($mode == '') {
                 $url = 'https://secure.payu.in/_payment.php';
             }

             return $url;
         }

         /**
          * Get debug flag
          *
          * @return string
          */
         public function getDebug() {
             return Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/' . $this->getCode() . '/debug_flag');
         }

         public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount) {
             $payment->setStatus(self::STATUS_APPROVED)
                     ->setLastTransId($this->getTransactionId());

             return $this;
         }

         public function cancel(Varien_Object $payment) {
             $payment->setStatus(self::STATUS_DECLINED)
                     ->setLastTransId($this->getTransactionId());

             return $this;
         }

         /**
          * parse response POST array from gateway page and return payment status
          *
          * @return bool
          */
         public function parseResponse() {

             return true;
         }

         /**
          * Return redirect block type
          *
          * @return string
          */
         public function getRedirectBlockType() {
             return $this->_redirectBlockType;
         }

         /**
          * Return payment method type string
          *
          * @return string
          */
         public function getPaymentMethodType() {
             return $this->_paymentMethod;
         }

         public function getResponseOperation($response) {

             $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
             $debug_mode = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/debug_mode');
             $key = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/key');
             $salt = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/payucheckout_shared/salt');

             if (isset($response['status'])) {
                 $txnid = $response['txnid'];
                 $orderid = $response['udf2'];
                 if ($response['status'] == 'success') {

                     $status = $response['status'];
                     $order->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
                     $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
                     $amount = $response['amount'];
                     $productinfo = $response['productinfo'];
                     $firstname = $response['firstname'];
                     $email = $response['email'];
                     $keyString = '';
                     $Udf1 = $response['udf1'];
                     $Udf2 = $response['udf2'];
                     $Udf3 = $response['udf3'];
                     $Udf4 = $response['udf4'];
                     $Udf5 = $response['udf5'];
                     $Udf6 = $response['udf6'];
                     $Udf7 = $response['udf7'];
                     $Udf8 = $response['udf8'];
                     $Udf9 = $response['udf9'];
                     $Udf10 = $response['udf10'];
                     if ($debug_mode == 1) {
                         $keyString = $key . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $amount . '|' . $productinfo . '|' . $firstname . '|' . $email . '|' .
 $Udf1 . '|' . $Udf2 . '|' . $Udf3 . '|' . $Udf4 . '|' . $Udf5 . '|' .
 $Udf6 . '|' . $Udf7 . '|' . $Udf8 . '|' . $Udf9 . '|' . $Udf10;
                     } else {
                         $keyString = $key . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $amount . '|' . $productinfo . '|' . $firstname . '|' . $email . '|' .
 $Udf1 . '|' . $Udf2 . '|' . $Udf3 . '|' . $Udf4 . '|' . $Udf5 . '|' .
 $Udf6 . '|' . $Udf7 . '|' . $Udf8 . '|' . $Udf9 . '|' . $Udf10;
                     }

                     $keyArray = explode("|", $keyString);
                     $reverseKeyArray = array_reverse($keyArray);
                     $reverseKeyString = implode("|", $reverseKeyArray);
                     $saltString = $salt . '|' . $status . '|' . $reverseKeyString;
                     $sentHashString = strtolower(hash('sha512', $saltString));
                     $responseHashString = $_REQUEST['hash'];
                     if ($sentHashString == $responseHashString) {
                         $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
                         $order->save();
                         $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                     } else {

                         $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
                         $order->cancel()->save();
                     }

                     if ($debug_mode == 1) {
                         $debugId = $response['udf1'];
                         $data = array('response_body' => implode(",", $response));
                         $model = Mage::getModel('payucheckout/api_debug')->load($debugId)->addData($data);
                         $model->setId($id)->save();
                     }
                 }

                 if ($response['status'] == 'failure') {
                     $order->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
                     $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
                     // Inventory updated 
                     $this->updateInventory($orderid);

                     $order->cancel()->save();

                     if ($debug_mode == 1) {
                         $debugId = $response['udf1'];
                         $data = array('response_body' => implode(",", $response));
                         $model = Mage::getModel('payucheckout/api_debug')->load($debugId)->addData($data);
                         $model->setId($id)->save();
                     }
                 } else if ($response['status'] == 'pending') {
                     $order->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
                     $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
                     // Inventory updated  
                     $this->updateInventory($orderid);
                     $order->cancel()->save();

                     if ($debug_mode == 1) {
                         $debugId = $response['udf1'];
                         $data = array('response_body' => implode(",", $response));
                         $model = Mage::getModel('payucheckout/api_debug')->load($debugId)->addData($data);
                         $model->setId($id)->save();
                     }
                 }
             } else {

                 $order->loadByIncrementId($response['id']);
                 $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
                 // Inventory updated 
                 $order_id = $response['id'];
                 $this->updateInventory($order_id);

                 $order->cancel()->save();
             }
         }

         public function updateInventory($order_id) {

             $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
             $items = $order->getAllItems();
             foreach ($items as $itemId => $item) {
                 $ordered_quantity = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
                 $sku = $item->getSku();
                 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                 $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId())->getQty();

                 $updated_inventory = $qtyStock + $ordered_quantity;

                 $stockData = $product->getStockItem();
                 $stockData->setData('qty', $updated_inventory);
                 $stockData->save();
             }
         }

     }
```

Comment: Do you want to update your status before payment success or after payment success?

Comment: after payment success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the status by writing observer.
you can use **observer** with two **events**
1.`checkout_submit_all_after`- this event call before redirect to payment gateway.
2.`sales_order_invoice_pay` - this event call after payment Success.

I ll give you a code for the observer.for this you want to create a module.
config.xml - path(app\code\local\Wired\Orders\etc)->Wired : Your Module Name, Orders:Your Model Name

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Wired_Orders>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wired_Orders>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <orders>
            <class>Wired_Orders_Model</class>
        </orders>
    </models>
    <events>

//using first option before redirect to payment Gateway

        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <change_order_status>
                    <class>orders/observer</class>
                    <method>CodeOrdeStatus</method>
                </change_order_status>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>

//using Second option After Payment Success Full

        <sales_order_invoice_pay>
            <observers>
                <change_order_status>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>orders/observer</class>
                    <method>sales_order_invoice_pay</method>
                </change_order_status>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_invoice_pay>
    </events>
 </global>
</config>
```

Now Go to you observer.php page where we are going to write methods to change the order status.(path - (app\code\local\Wired\Orders\Model)

```
class Wired_Orders_Model_Observer
{
//This function for checkout_submit_all_after event
public function CodeOrdeStatus($observer){

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
    //check order is based on your payment method code. 
    //here for example i use the cash on delivery payment method
    if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="cashondelivery"):

    //$order->setData('state', "complete");
    $order->setStatus("cod");
    //You can change what ever the status according to your requirement instead of cod
    $order->save(); 
    endif;
}
//This function for sales_order_invoice_pay event
public function sales_order_invoice_pay($observer){
    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
    $order = $invoice->getOrder();
    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
    // check order is based on your payment method code. here for example i use the cash on delivery payment method 
    if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="cashondelivery"):

    //$order->setData('state', "complete");
    $order->setStatus("cod");//You can change what ever the status according to your requirement instead of cod
    $order->save(); 
    endif;
}
}
```

Do not forget active your module before check.To activate your module upload this file(Wired_Orders.xml) to your Path(app\etc\modules)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Wired_Orders>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Wired_Orders>
</modules>
```

**Update**
yes you can add the $order->setStatus("your status"); 
in the function 
`getResponseOperation(){}` 
line

```
if ($sentHashString == $responseHashString) {
//change this line 
   $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
//to this line 
$order->setStatus("your status");
                         $order->save();
                         $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                     }
```

But Kindly notice that updating the status using observer also fine.

Comment: there is anyway to do changes in my given code i dont want to create module.

Comment: ill update the answer

Comment: hello in ccavenue i also want to do this same changes but not work.. here is the code

Comment: if($order_status == "Success")
  {
    
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
   $order->loadByIncrementId($Order_Id); 
    
   $f_passed_status = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/ccavenuepay/payment_success_status');
   $message = Mage::helper('Ccavenuepay')->__('Your payment is authorized.');
   $order->setState($f_passed_status, true, $message);
    
   
   if($order_history_comments !='') $order->addStatusHistoryComment($order_history_comments,true);
   
   $payment_confirmation_mail = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/ccavenuepay/payment_confirmation_mail'